# Can't reach nested JSON in python 3.8

Tags: python, json, websocket, syntax

Working with a response from a Websockets subscription.

The response reads like this:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'subscription', 'params': {'channel': 'book.BTC-PERPETUAL.none.1.100ms', 'data': {'timestamp': 1588975154127, 'instrument_name': 'BTC-PERPETUAL', 'change_id': 19078703948, 'bids': [[10019.5, 8530.0]], 'asks': [[10020.0, 506290.0]]}}}
```

And I'm trying to reach the first and only values inside  `"bids"` and `"asks"` arrays via `json.loads()`

Code looks like this:

```
   async def __async__get_ticks(self):
  async with self.ws as echo:
     await echo.send(json.dumps(self.request))
     while True:
            response = await echo.receive()
            responseJson = json.loads(response)
            print(responseJson["params"]["data"])
```

And error says:

> ```
> print(responseJson["params"]["data"])
> ```
>
> KeyError: 'params'

However I try, it doesn't want to catch any of the JSON after `"jsonprc"`, for which it successfully returns `2.0`. Anything beyond that always comes up with an error.

I tried using `.get()`, and it helps to go one level deeper, but still not more.

Any ideas on how to format this properly and reach the `bids` and `asks` ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the `dict.get()` method, but make sure that you set it to return an empty dictionary when querying dictionaries that are expected to have nested dicts.

By default (if you don't specify a second argument to `dict.get()`), it will return `None`. This explains why you were only able to go one level deep.

Here's an example:

```
empty_dict = {}
two_level_dict = {
    "one": {
        "level": "deeper!"
    }
}

# This will return None and the second get call will not fail, because
# the first get returned an empty dict for the .get("level") call to succeed. 
first_get = empty_dict.get("one", {}).get("level")

# This will return 'deeper!'
second_get = two_level_dict.get("one", {}).get("level")

print(first_get)
print(second_get)
```